# How do you find the probability that the sample mean is between 52 and 56?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, sampling

I was attempting to help a friend with a question and I am not sure if I am overthinking it, or simply missing an assumption I can make.  It goes like this:

The average life of a battery is 50 hours with a standard deviation of 4 hours.  What is the probability that the mean of 16 samples is between 52 and 56?

I thought I had this, but I am getting caught up on the fact that it is a small sample size and it is not stated that it is normally distributed.

Question:  What method do you use to solve this?

Other people suggested:

$$Z = \frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma}$$

My problem here is we are assuming it is normal and we are not utilizing the given info about the sample size of 16.

I suggested:

$$Z = \frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$$
My problem here is we are again assuming it is normal and I am getting $2<Z<6$, which gives about $2\%$.

Any clarifications will be greatlyappreciated!

Comment: As no distribution is mentioned, the question probabobably intends you to apply the Central Limit Theorem. However, the question does not ask for an approximation, so assuming that you have not misquoted the question, I would  answer that insufficient information is provided to answer the question as given, and then sack the lecturer.

Comment: @wolfies Thank you!  I have reread it many times and I have lost sleep, but I believe he does want them to use the CLT.  I did conclude that she should write that there is insufficient info.  If we are to use the CLT, then I only use $\sigma$ in the denominator, which gives about a $24\%$ probability?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be getting a $97\%$ probability for the mean as (assuming a symmetric distribution) there is a $50\%$ probability the sample mean is below the population mean of $50$

If $Z$ has a standard normal distribution then $P(2 \lt Z \lt 6) \approx 0.999999999 - 0.977249868 \approx 0.02275$, so just over $2\%$

As a simulation in R

```
set.seed(99)
cases <- 10^5
n <- 16
matdat <- matrix(rnorm(cases*n, mean=50, sd=4), ncol=n)
rm <- rowMeans(matdat)
mean(rm > 52 & rm < 56)
```

gives `0.02263` - close to correct given simulation error

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  I accidentally sutracted .9999 - (1-.97).

Comment: By CLT $\bar X \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(\mu_{\bar X}=50,\, \sigma_{\bar X} = \sigma/\sqrt{n} = 1)$ and `diff(pnorm(c(52,56), 50, 1))` returns
 0.02275013. Twice (+1)